# How to create new SQL instance in groovy using secure DB2 z/OS connection?

Tags: db2-zos, groovy-sql

I am groovy beginner with minimal java knowledge. Trying to access DB2 z/OS from groovy script.

With not secure connection below sample works fine for me:

```
import java.sql.*; 
import groovy.sql.Sql 

// DB2 
 sql = Sql.newInstance( 'jdbc:db2://host:port/DATABASE', 'MyUID', 'MyPassword','com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver' )

sql.eachRow('select date(current date) as TODAY_DATE from sysibm.sysdummy1') 
 {tp ->
     println "Today is ${tp.TODAY_DATE}"
 }
 
sql.close()
```

But when I need to establish secure connection, I need to specify also path to certificate and password.

How to modify my "Sql.newInstance" call to establish secure connection to DB2 z/OS?

Answer (score 0):

It's occurred to be quite easy. Below is the sample:

```
import java.sql.*; 
import groovy.sql.Sql 

// DB2 
 sql = Sql.newInstance( 'jdbc:db2://host:port/DATABASE**:sslConnection=true;sslTrustStoreLocation=/path/to/certificate;sslTrustStorePassword=MyCertPasswd;', 'MyUID', 'MyPassword','com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver'** )

sql.eachRow('select date(current date) as TODAY_DATE from sysibm.sysdummy1') 
 {tp ->
     println "Today is ${tp.TODAY_DATE}"
 }
 
sql.close()
```